# How to create convincing rain with a particle system

Tags: particles

How would i go about creating a scene similar to this image. I am especially interested in the how the droplets not only are deflected, but also 'roll off' the subject.

[image: img]

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Was this made in Blender? That looks sick and something I might try. Also, a potential starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toMoatlkL5c

Comment: I'm not sure what this was made in sorry. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you know how basic particle systems work.
If not i recommend watching a tutorial on basic particle systems ([like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlTdyPegZOk)).

Just spawn the particles like you would do normally.

Then add collision to your surface (the creature in the gif from your op) and set the Particle Dampening.

[image]

As you can see on the image, some particles are bouncing off, some sliding down the surface.
Hope it helps.